# wand.exceptions.ConfigureError: RegistryKeyLookupFailed

Tags: python, imagemagick

[image]

I'm trying to convert some PDFs to jpegs using imagemagick . I'm working on win 10, 64 with python 3.62 - 64 bit and wand 0.4.4. I've been able to get wand working with ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16-HDRI. I've set the Path and MAGICK_HOME env vars  to

```
"E:\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16-HDR"
```

This allow:

```
from wand.image import Image
```

to work.

Later in the script I have:

```
file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"\\myfile.pdf"

image_pdf = Image(filename=file_path, resolution=300)
image_jpeg = image_pdf.convert('jpeg')
```

I'm getting:

```
  File "E:/ENVS/r3/pdfminer.six/ocr_test.py", line 32, in <module>
    image_pdf = Image(filename=file_path, resolution=300)
  File "E:\myenv\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 2744, in __init__
    self.read(filename=filename, resolution=resolution)
  File "E:\myenv\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 2822, in read
    self.raise_exception()
  File "E:\myenv\lib\site-packages\wand\resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.ConfigureError: RegistryKeyLookupFailed `CoderModulesPath' @ error/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/663
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer based on https://github.com/dahlia/wand/issues/299. add the following:

```
magick_home=os.getcwd() + os.sep + "E:\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16-HDR"
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + magick_home + os.sep
os.environ["MAGICK_HOME"] = magick_home
os.environ["MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH"] = magick_home + os.sep + "modules" + os.sep + "coders"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you did not install ImageMagick on your computer.
ImageMagick needs to be installed with the setup :
[setup exe](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)